# How can I align outputs (charts) in Google Colab?

Tags: python, output, alignment, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to align code outputs in Google Colab?

In Jupyter Notebook, I use

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

display(HTML("""
<style>
.output {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
"""))
```

Which makes the outputs of the code (e.g. plotly chart) aligned to center.
Google Colab does not throw any error but it completely ignores the code and everything is still left aligned. Anybody run into this issue and solved it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Colab outputs are in their own iframe, so CSS defined in one output will not affect the display of other outputs. Further, the DOM structure of cell outputs in Colab is slightly different than that in either Jupyter notebook or JupyterLab (which themselves slightly differ from each other).

Try putting this **in the same cell** as the charts you're creating:

```
display(HTML("""
<style>
#output-body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
"""))
```

Example:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

display(HTML("""
<style>
#output-body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
"""))

import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip",
                width=300, height=300)

fig.show()
fig.show()
```

[image]